# R - looping across 2 objects

Tags: regex, r, loops, for-loop, grepl

I'm trying to do something fairly simple (I think) but I can't get my head round it. I'm trying to write a loop that checks if a character variable in a data frame contains any of a certain list of substrings, and to assign a corresponding value to a dummy variable.

so, imagine a data.frame, n=2000, with a variable `data.frame$text`. Furthermore, I have a character vector containing all the substrings I want to text `data.frame$text` for. Let's call it `hillary_exists` :

```
hillary_exists <- c("Hilary Clinton", "hilary clinton","hilaryclinton", "hillaryclinton", "HilaryClinton",
                    "HillaryClinton","Hillary Clinton", "Hillary Rodham Clinton", "Hillary", "Hilary", "#Hillary2016", "#ImWithHer",
                    "Hillary2016", "hillary", "hilary", "Clinton 2016", "Clinton", "Secretary of State Clinton", 
                    "Senator Clinton", "Hilary Rodham", "Hilary Rodham Clinton", "Hilary Rodham-Clinton", "Hillary Rodham-Clinton")
```

**Now, I want my loop to test every row of `data.frame$text` for the existence of every element of `hillary_exists`, and if any of them is `TRUE`, to generate a new value of `1` for the variable `data.frame$hillary_mention`** . This is what I tried:

```
for(i in hillary_exists){
  if(grepl(hillary_exists[i], data.frame$text)){
    data.frame$hillary_mention <- 1
  } else {
    data.frame$hillary_mention <- 0 }
}
```

But obviously I'm missing the `i` component for the `data.frame$text` element, but I don't know how to address it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks for your comment, can you perhaps elaborate a bit on that? As far as  I can tell, that's pretty much what I did, isn't it?

Comment: like this, `data.frame$hillary_mention[i] <- 1`

Comment: How about `data.frame$hillary_mention <- sapply(data.frame$text,function(s) any(grepl(s,hillary_exists)))`?

Comment: @brittenb, perhaps you're right, but it's not clear to me what is the desired behavior of the algorithm. @nikUoM, Say, we have `hillary_exist <- c('ab','bc','cd')` and `d <- data.frame(text=c(letters[1:5],'ab','de'))`; what is the expected output in this case?

Comment: It seems to me that this code might give the proper solution: `data.frame$hillary_mention <- match(data.frame$text,hillary_exists,nomatch=0) `. Even better: `data.frame$hillary_mention <- data.frame$text %in% hillary_exists `

Comment: Hi everyone! Thanks so much for your replies. I'm really sorry I didn't get back to you earlier, I was on a work trip yesterday so couldn't get on the internet. Anyway - @brittenb 's implementation worked, thanks so much! The other ones sadly didn't produce the desired outcome for me.  do you want to write that up as an answer so I can upvote it? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach we can use to get this to work is to turn `hillary_exists` into a regex: `hillary_regex <- paste(hillary_exists, collapse = "|")`. Essentially, this just takes all of your terms and turns it into a big OR statement. This takes care of one of the loops for us automatically. Next, we just loop over our text column, `data.frame$text`, using `sapply`.

```
data.frame$hillary_mention <- sapply(data.frame$text, function(s) grepl(hillary_regex, s, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

It's good to use `ignore.case = TRUE` here because there may be mentions in the text that aren't accounted for in `hillary_exists`, such as "hIllary cLinTon".